# Highlight mat-form-field on invalid value without [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular, ngmodel, mat-form-field

I have a mat-form-field with the following input inside of a form :

```
<input matInput name="input" type="number" step="any" (input)="doSomething()" required />
```

The input is marked as required but is not highlighted in red when emptied : [image: mat-form-field not highlighted even though invalid]

But if I had a binding with `[(ngModel)]` like below, the red highlight appears : [image: mat-form-field correctly highlighted]

```
<input matInput name="input" type="number" step="any" (input)="doSomething()" required [(ngModel)]="whyDoINeedThis"  />
```

Is there a way I can avoid having to bind to a useless variable just to get invalid highlights without having to mark the field as invalid manually or do the styling myself ?

Answer (score -1):

When Setting your form in ts, try giving the control a required validator.

the form in your ts should have this.

```
input = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
```